# Magento 2 Tabs widget - unbind arrow keys

Tags: magento2, javascript, tabs, widget, widget-instance

I am wondering if there is any clean way to unbind keyboard (left and right arrows) from mage/tabs widget? This is how I init tabs in my custom-script.js:

```
`var tabs = $('#element').tabs({
     "openedState": "active"
 });`
```

[This is tabs source code](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.0/lib/web/mage/tabs.js)

But both `tabs.unbind('keydown');` and `tabs.unbind('_keydown');` don't work.

**edit:**
Solved, `"openOnFocus": false` disable keyboard navigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, `"openOnFocus": false` disable keyboard navigation.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/104097)

Comment: Used, thanks. But honestly, this is complete answers for the base question. What would you like to add more? :)